# How do I update a MySQL table with values dependent of each other in one Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, simultaneous

For instance, my main query inserts a new row into table REF_STORES which has a structure like this:

ID   |   Store_Name   |   VariableA   |   VariableA+VariableB   |   VariableC+VariableA

In My Case, I am pulling each one of these fields from one of two different tables. ID and Store Name come from one, while the others (VariableA, VariableB, and VariableC) come from another. What I cannot figure out is how to pull all these variables from the two different tables and simultaneously calculate, then insert the results into the table structure above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a SELECT query that will pull the values from both tables simultaneously? If you do, you can do something like:

```
INSERT INTO REF_STORES (id, store_name, var_a, var_ab, var_ca)
SELECT id, store_name, var_a, var_a + var_b, var_c + var_a
FROM [however you're joining the two tables]
```